# fast java Input\Output Stream

Tags: java, inputstream, outputstream, java-io

i have a servlet that copies a pdf file to the client using response output stream

```
private boolean copyStreamToStream(InputStream in, OutputStream target) {

    logger.info("start copy file to stream");
    try {

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 8];
        int len = in.read(buffer);
        while (len != -1) {
            target.write(buffer, 0, len);
            len = in.read(buffer);
        }
        in.close();
        target.flush();
        target.close();
        logger.info("end copy file to stream");

    } catch (Exception ex) {

        logger.error("Error: ", ex);
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}
```

the InputStream for the pdf file on disk and OutputStream for response.getOutputStream()

the problem is that the PDF file is a big file and it takes a very long time to load it on client is there is any way to speed it up???

Comment: Did you use a BufferedInputStream ? It's the first thing to do from a FileInputStream.

Comment: 0 out of 6 questions with accepted answers... hmm, you might want to work on that.

Comment: @dystroy BufferedInputStream uses a buffer of 8 KB by default. The OP is already using an 8 KB buffer.

Comment: You need to determine where the delay is and what you mean by the client being slow.  How long does it take to just download i.e. with `wget`?  How much bandwidth do you have?

Comment: On an unrelated note, is [usually is a good idea](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2008/10/java-how-not-to-make-mess-of-stream.html) to put `close()` calls into `finally` block, because if any of the methods before them throw an exception, the streams won't get closed.

Answer (score 1):

Send the file for download instead of passing it back as direct response object.

```
// Set the headers.
response.setContentType("application/x-download");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);

// Send the file for download.
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream(  );
```

Edited.

Comment: That doesn't send 'a file for download'. That just sends the filename, twice.

Comment: Revision assumes file is text. If you use `InputStream` and `OutputStream` there is no assumption.

Comment: Sure! I have removed the noice to enable him use the origal `InputStream` as depicted in his code to avoid confusion.